# How to insert a CKEditor plugin in a Rails 3 app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor

I'm trying to use the wordcouter plugin for CKEditor. I was following along with [this](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_plugins), but it doesn't seem to work. After poking around for a bit, I've discovered that there are numerous different `config.js` files and numerous `plugin` directories. Which one(s) am I supposed to use?

```
app/assets/ckeditor/plugins/
app/assets/ckeditor/_source/plugins/
app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/plugins/
app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/_source/plugins/
app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/_source/core/plugins.js
app/assets/ckeditor/_source/core/plugins.js
```

When I unzip wordcount, it gives me a directory titled `wordcount_1.05`, am I supposed to rename this to just `wordcount`?

I'm typing the following into my `config.js` files:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'wordcount';

config.wordcount = {

      // Whether or not you want to show the Word Count
      showWordCount: true,

      // Whether or not you want to show the Char Count
      showCharCount: false
};
```

but this doesn't seem to do anything at all. If I modify it slightly (this only works in my app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js file) to make it:

`CKEDITOR.config`
then my text boxes stop displaying at all. So I feel like this is the correct file to be modifying.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am having the same issue here and am unsure of where to put my plugin! I am using the gem 'CKEditor'. My folder structure is currently: app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js This is working, but unsure where to add the plugins folder!

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  I'm running into the same problems

Comment: @scientiffic, I actually ended up completely scrapping the project and rebuilt it with Rails4. My best bet is that it was just some jumbled legacy code that wouldn't let me budge it. If you can start from scratch, salman's answer should work.

Comment: hm, that's not really an option for me, but thanks for the response.

Comment: @scientiffic, I didn't think that was an option for me either, but 2 years later here I am with a brand new app haha!

Comment: @XMLSlayer, Were you using the 'ckeditor' gem in this case? I seem to have run into the same problem

Comment: @PlagueHammer I was using every sort of ckeditor possible, which was probably the problem in the first place. I inherited the app from someone else, and they were using the gem, plus the plugin code in vendor, and public, and everywhere else imaginable.

Answer (score 3):

Put the plugin directories in app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/plugins/ (works for me in Rails 4.)

Comment: hey could you please provide the step by step info ?